# LibGDX controllers: how to fix crashes in JRuby?

Tags: java, libgdx, controllers, ruby

I'm using JRuby with LibGDX and it's been going quite swimmingly, save for a crash I experience every time I try to use the controllers extension.

Here's a basic rundown:

1. I've required all the related jars (`gdx-controllers.jar`, `gdx-controllers-desktop.jar`, and `gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar`).
2. I've imported the controllers package via `import "com.badlogic.gdx.controllers"`.
3. I call `Controllers.controllers`, which goes to the [getControllers](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-controllers/gdx-controllers/src/com/badlogic/gdx/controllers/Controllers.java#L47) method.
4. My game crashes with this error:

   `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type OIS::Exception: CocoaInputManager::_parseConfigSettings >> Unable to find a window or event target`

I think the error is due to a lack of a view being passed to OIS library ([here's an online view of a related source](http://hg.skewedaspect.com/ois-ogre/src/5ce7d2308b26b6e204b2ecf5b4fea5ae93e8010a/src/mac/CocoaInputManager.mm#cl-41)).

How do I prevent the controllers extension from crashing my game? More importantly, how do I make it *work*? :)

Comment: When do you call that `_intialize` function?  If you call it before  the `Gdx` is done loading itself, then things will break.  For example, if you create and pass your `InputManager` to your game constructor, that would be too early.  It would be safe to call it in the various platforms' `OnCreate` methods.

Comment: I'm calling this much after Gdx is available. I'm calling it after I'm already rendering textures, etc.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @ashes999 Unfortunately, no. I think it may be something wrong with the natives being loaded, though.

Comment: Try asking on the relevant forum (libGDX or OIS) and maybe that'll help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a library bug best addressed by its developers.